# Tiva Launchpad for USB Read/Write

Tags: usb, texas-instruments, launchpad

Is it possible to write/read text files on a USB Mass Storage Device using one of the USB ports on the Tiva Launchpad?

Answer (score 1):

I have only opened the box and run the examples but it is definitely possible to read text files from a USB stick -- it is one of the examples provided by TI.

Comment: Can you describe or link to the example?